# Variable value inside loop vs. outside loop

Tags: python

I'm curious why the following blocks of syntax treat the variable "ans" differently depending on where "ans" is in the code. In the first example, "ans" increments/decrements correctly based on user input. In the second, "ans" stays equal to the original value (in this case 50) despite user input. The variables "low" and "high" are outside of the loop but still save the values from the loop, while "ans" is outside the loop and does not. Appreciate the help.

1.

```
low = 0
high = 100

print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
while True:
    ans = int((high + low)/2)
    print("Is your secret number", str(ans), "?")
    x = input("Enter h if too high, l if too low, or c if correct: ")
    if x == "l":
        low = ans
    elif x == "h":
        high = ans
    elif x == "c":
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: ", ans)
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry I did not understand your input.")
        x = input("Enter h if too high, l if too low, or c if correct: ")
```

2.

```
low = 0
high = 100
ans = int((high + low)/2)

print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
while True:
    print("Is your secret number", str(ans), "?")
    x = input("Enter h if too high, l if too low, or c if correct: ")
    if x == "l":
        low = ans
    elif x == "h":
        high = ans
    elif x == "c":
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: ", ans)
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry I did not understand your input.")
        x = input("Enter h if too high, l if too low, or c if correct: ")
```

Comment: In 1, `ans` gets recalculated each time with the updated values of `high` and `low`. In 2, `ans = int((high + low)/2)` only gets executed once with the original values of `high` and `low`.

Comment: Thanks - followup question for @JohnnyMopp would be why do high and low values get recalculated each time when they are outside of the loop? And why does that not feed into ans to recalculate in 2)?

Comment: 1. `high` and `low` are modified at `high = ans` and `low = ans`. 2. `ans = int((high + low)/2)` is outside the loop (int the 2nd example) so that line only executes once - before the loop is entered.

Comment: @user9232479 You don't seem to understand how assignments work. A statement like `ans = int((high + low)/2)` doesn't describe a relationship between the variables that's updated automatically. It simply performs the arithmetic and stores the result in `ans` once.